Celery Tasks not getting executed as but worker and beat are running perfectly
I have an app that runs with no problem, i recently switched from APScheduler to Celery.
I have setup the redis server for it and celery tasks seem to be running smoothly from outside.
I have started the celery worker and beat in separate terminals.
My app should give out output whenever the task is executed. But there is no output
The code for my app.py:
#I have imported everything required

#creating the app
app = Flask(__name__, static_folder='static')

#configuring the celery app
app.config['broker_url'] = 'redis://localhost:6379/0'
app.config['result_backend'] = 'redis://localhost:6379/0'

#creating the celery app
celery = Celery(app.name, broker=app.config['broker_url'])
celery.conf.update(app.config)

app.secret_key = '9557186409'

#configuring the database
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///site.db'
db.init_app(app)

webhook_url = "https://chat.googleapis.com/v1/spaces/AAAA0XTp2i8/messages?key=AIzaSyDdI0hCZtE6vySjMm-WEfRq3CPzqKqqsHI&token=4sX2rjnS34sBcb6Q7tKN800_IHQbcHCB76lW_0rbxqw"


def send_message_to_chat(message):
    data = {"text": message}
    response = requests.post(webhook_url, json=data)
    print(f"Message sent to chat: {response.status_code}")

with app.app_context():
    #creating the databases
    db.create_all()

index_routes(app)
librarian_routes(app)
student_routes(app)


login_manager = LoginManager()
login_manager.init_app(app)
login_manager.login_view = 'login_session_not_found'


@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(user_id):
    return users_db.query.get(user_id)

@celery.task
def test_celery():
    print("Celery task executed at ", datetime.now())

@celery.task
def check_expiry():
    try:
        print("Executing check_expiry task at ", datetime.now())
        issued = requests_db.query.filter_by(status='issued').all()
        for issue in issued:
            if issue.end_date and issue.end_date < datetime.now():
                print(f"Issue {issue.id} is expired.")
                issue.status = "completed"
        db.session.commit()
        print("check_expiry task completed.")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error in check_expiry task: {e}")


@celery.task
def send_reminder():
    with app.app_context():
        print("Sending reminders ", datetime.now())
        send_message_to_chat("Sending reminders")
        current_time = datetime.now()
        for user in users_db.query.all():
            #check if current time is the preferred time of the user, if last reminder was not sent in the current date
            if user.preferred_hour == current_time.hour:
                if user.last_reminder_datetime == None or user.last_reminder_datetime.date() != current_time.date():
                    send_message_to_chat(f"Reminder for {user.username}")
                    user.last_reminder_datetime = current_time
                    db.session.commit()

celery.conf.beat_schedule = {
    "check_expiry": {
        "task": "app.check_expiry",
        #runs every minute
        "schedule": crontab(minute="*")
    },
    "send_reminder": {
        "task": "app.send_reminder",
        #runs every hour
        "schedule": crontab(minute="*")
    },
    "test_celery": {
        "task": "app.test_celery",
        #runs every minute
        "schedule": crontab(minute="*")
    }
}

#starting the app
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
    

I am using a venv to run this app. I have tried running the worker and beat inside and outside the venv.
Worker initialization:
celery -A app.celery worker --loglevel=info
Beat initialization:
celery -A app.celery beat --loglevel=info
Worker Terminal:
[2024-07-31 16:38:00,004: INFO/MainProcess] Task app.test_celery[1f068e64-4cb4-43ad-b1d3-f7cd91bd0a5f] received
[2024-07-31 16:38:00,007: INFO/MainProcess] Task app.send_reminder[9520a809-4833-43b3-9964-520d13f26fa2] received
[2024-07-31 16:38:00,008: INFO/MainProcess] Task app.check_expiry[26f91af5-c07e-4acd-b816-a36cc299a947] received

Beat Terminal:
[2024-07-31 16:38:00,000: INFO/MainProcess] Scheduler: Sending due task test_celery (app.test_celery)
[2024-07-31 16:38:00,001: INFO/MainProcess] Scheduler: Sending due task send_reminder (app.send_reminder)
[2024-07-31 16:38:00,004: INFO/MainProcess] Scheduler: Sending due task check_expiry (app.check_expiry)

All this and there is no python output
I have tried removing the debug=true option, I have tried to make a simple celery task to check things, I have tried restarting the app, worker and beat.
I also tried asking gpt4o for help and still nothing.
Still no output.

If you are running on windows please use
 celery -A app.celery worker --loglevel=info -P solo

The default prefork doesnt work in windows. Check this article
